# Dart: Can i use it to create software with GUI?

Tags: windows, macos, user-interface, dart

I started falling in love with Dart and Flutter, and now I've the need to create a mini utility for Mac Os. It needs a very very simple user interface, and so I'm here just to ask you if this is possibile at all, (at september of 2018) and if it's possibile at least for Windows.

### Can Dart create simple GUI programs?

- For Mac?
- For Linux?
- For Windows?

Comment: Why would this not be possible? Visual Studio Code has a GUI, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AngularDart in a web browser is clearly a GUI.  Some people are working on putting Flutter in a canvas similar to Electron.